Does Google see the data sent via Google Tag Manager?
If I have custom database which I can send some PII data to, will Google be able to see what was the content of the function (e.g. the object I included there) I used to send it?
I'm not sending it to Google Analytics or anything of the sort, of course.
I'd just include the send_event(data) function, which does not interact with Google services apart from GTM.

No.
Client side Google Tag Manager is a Javacript injector. It bundles the script required for your tracking and marketing tags and sends them to the browser, where the script is injected into the page. If you load your gtm.js file from the Google domain Google gets the ip address and other http headers from the user, but that is about it.
Tags are then executed in the browser, and the tracking requests are then send to the urls configured in the tags (if you want to test that your data is not sent to any illict targets you can look into the network tab of your browser or use a proxy to check outgoing data). Google is no longer involved at this point (unless you specifically conifgure Google tags, but you said you are not doing that).
(Server-side Google tag manager additionally sends some requests to Google, but these do not contain any data from the requests, they have some basic usage information. I assume from your question that you are using client-side GTM only, so this is just à titre d'information and does not affect you.)
